# Why is the output of this circuit always 12V?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

[image: image of the circuit]

I have a circuit that is intended to provide an output voltage of 12V when the input signal from a microcontroller is 3.3V.

When the input signal is 0V, the output voltage should be 0V.

Regardless of the input voltage, the output voltage remains constant at 12V. The circuit diagram is shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ll9.png).

How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the circuit operates as intended, with the output voltage corresponding to the input voltage levels?

Comment: What does the signal connect to?

Comment: Where does the *input signal from a microcontroller* go? How have you established *Circuit output Always 12V*?

Comment: Q2 is drawn inverted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bad idea for a circuit, you have just missed the real world implications of leakage currents. 
Andy has already given you a proper answer with the same suggestions that I would have given you, I will only make a schematic that is easier to understand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUbzaI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Since you have provided the PCB layout asking how to do the modification, I have edited your image with the suggested areas for adding the two resistors.
[image]
You can simply solder the 100k resistor across the existing pads for base and emitter as I have indicated in the image. 
The other resistor, which can be anywhere from 100k to 1M would be placed from the collector to the ground plane which you will have to expose for soldering (scratch the mask in a small square as indicated).

Comment: It appears rather peculiar to remove the load from the emitter. Could you kindly explain to me why removing the load from the emitter wouldn't have any adverse effects?. Considering that I already have the PCB fully assembled and soldered, and currently lack the capacity to undertake new hardware developments, it would necessitate resorting to a makeshift solution. I would like to inquire whether utilizing a MOSFET with an SOT-23 package could potentially yield the desired outcome?

Comment: @Marina There are so called "digital transistors" in SOT23 case (e.g. DDTA114YCA), that already contain these resistors (R2 and R3 in this schematic).

Comment: @Marina The emitter is the electrode with an arrow. The output electrode is collector. If you give us a picture of your PCB, we could help you figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: This is the circuit on my PCB. To make it clearer, "PE10_REGEN" is the 3v3 signal, and "REGEN_1" is the output that needs to be either 12V or 0V. Q4 is an NPN transistor, and Q3 is a PNP transistor. [PCB bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmgwG.png), [PCB top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCiBf.png), 
[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTROD.png)

Comment: @EdinFifić I will use the solution that you and Andy provided me with. My biggest challenge is figuring out the best way to do it since my PCB is already printed. I added a new response to include some images of my PCB as you requested. I hope that adding some jumpers for the circuit to work doesn't compromise the reliability of the circuit.

Comment: @Marina I have edited your PCB image with suggestions and added it to my answer at the bottom. Even if you're not very skilled at soldering, you should be able to do a fine job on it.

Answer (score 4):

You have no load on the signal output pin hence, any leakage through Q2 from emitter to collector (a guaranteed effect in real life and simulators) will inevitably produce 12 volts at the output.

Try a 1 MΩ load to ground on the output and you might see less than 1 volt when Q2 is off: -

[image]

It might also help (in real life) with this in blue: -

[image]

Comment: It appears rather peculiar to remove the load from the emitter. Could you kindly explain to me why removing the load from the emitter wouldn't have any adverse effects?. Considering that I already have the PCB fully assembled and soldered, and currently lack the capacity to undertake new hardware developments, it would necessitate resorting to a makeshift solution. I would like to inquire whether utilizing a MOSFET with an SOT-23 package could potentially yield the desired outcome?

Comment: @Marina what "load from the emitter" are you referring to? All emitters in these designs  are connected to ground or Vcc, and any loads shown are *all* on the collector side.

Comment: @Marina have you deleted a question you asked (maybe yesterday or the day before) and one that I might have commented on?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about how the circuit behaves in simulation, or in the real world?

Add a 100K resistor from the Q2 base to Vcc.  This will assure a rapid and complete turn-off of Q1.  An alternate location is from the Q1 collector to Vcc.

To make your schematic a bit more readable. turn over Q2 so the emitter is going up to Vcc.  That makes it more clear that the output is being pulled *up* to Vcc by Q2.